Joining tables is causing a duplicate record with a different value in other column
I'm trying to join 3 tables and somehow, I'm getting a duplicate record with a different variant in one of my date columns. for reference here is the sample content of the table:
Table A



key1
key2
quant




123zxc
abc123
1


456asd
def456
2



Table B



key1
key2
order_date




123zxc
abc123
20230101


456asd
def456
20230101



Table C



key1
key2
delivery_date




123zxc
abc123
20230201


456asd
def456
20230202



Output



key1
key2
quant
order_date
delivery_date




123zxc
abc123
1
20230101
20230201


456asd
def456
2
20230101
20230202


123zxc
abc123
2
20230101
20230202


456asd
def456
1
20230101
20230201



SELECT DISTINCT
      a.key1,
      a.key2,       
      a.quant,
      b.order_date,
      c.delivery_date
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.key1 = b.key1 AND a.key2 = b.key2
INNER JOIN tableC c ON a.key1 = c.key1 AND a.key2 = c.key2

The ideal output should only be 2 rows, I tried removing the delivery_date column and the result is 2 rows. Should I add additional conditions for my joins?
Note that the last 2 rows are the incorrect value.

Your query is correct and doesn't need DISTINCT. It returns two rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZDi9dS1D Are you sure you didn't make a typo in your original query?

Yes, there is no typo, it's weird that it's creating a separate variant for each value

This should only be happening if you are incorrectly joining one of the three tables (e.g. only by key1, or by the wrong table alias)

I guess there is a problem with my query.

Maybe you can share the actual query you are using, or just the joins so we can check

I rechecked my source tables turns out I provided the incorrect data here is the corrected version.
https://dbfiddle.uk/2kIFWcEF

I change a position of column quantity to table b

In that example the 'keys' in tableB en tableC aren't unique anymore, leading to 4 records.

Are there any work around for this? Because unfortunately that is the given structure for the table

Hi @NathanaelTomAterado please update your question to show the corrected data
